# Hibernate : connection.datasource

Tags: java, hibernate

in the hibernate.cfg.xml that I have, there is :

```
<property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/persystddo</property>
```

I don't really understand what it means. I saw that it can manage the hibernate transactions, so maybe it can resolve my problem. 
What I understand, is that my database should me in JNDI datasource. But where can I access it ? Can someone help me and tell me what it means ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It retrieves the bean from application server rather than from your application configuration.  Check the data sources configuration in your application server.